# Chrome extension - Document.getelementbyId(...) evaluating to null?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In console I can input document.getElementById('...') and get a value back. Or even .textContent and get the string I want.

Once I pop this into my chrome extension and run it, it evaluates document.getElementById('...') as null. What's up?

Manifest.json:

```
 {
   "name": "CSUF RMP",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "description": "Displays professor ratings on icon click",
  "background" : {
     "scripts" : ["background.js"]

   },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon16.png"
   },

  "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://mycsuf.fullerton.edu/*"],
            "js": ["script.js"]

        }
    ],

   "permissions": ["<all_urls>", "*://*/*", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}
```

Background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "script.js"});
 });
```

My script.js is literally what I posted at the top. The script is supposed to have access to the web page's DOM (thus I need a content script) and run it on click of the icon (hence the background.js)

I can get the page to run and show an alert or something, but that line isn't evaluating the page's dom, just null.

Comment: `document.getElementById('...')` - really? I didn't think an ID could have `...` as a value

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what is the problem here,

you are executing script.js just like a normal script, and a normal script can't interact with the page DOM, you can think about it as just runing a script from a file- it don't have the content script's privileges that way.

What you can do is open a new tab (with the url of the content script), and then pass to the content script at that new tab a message which tells him to run a specific function there.

You can test it without using message sending by setting the onload of the content script to something like: `onload=alert(document.getElementById('...'));` and than open a new tab from the background page: `chrome.tabs.create({"url":"https://mycsuf.fullerton.edu"});`

tell me how it goes :)

Edit: forgot to mention that you need the 'tabs' permission in your manifest file in order to open new tabs and test the thing out.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean a new full blown tab? I see what you're saying about because of the executescript code in background.js, it's not being run as a content script (thus no DOM access). So I would need to have background.js send a msg when the icon is clicked (right now it executes the script). Then the msg is picked up by my content script, script.js with some event listener. Then it is now a "real" content script. Right?

Comment: Exactly. Sending messages can be a bit annoying so I thought you may prefer to check this faster by just open a new tab and let the content script run on it.

Comment: can you explain what a new tab means? I understand it to mean like a literal tab will open on my browser. --- My goal is to have on that mycsuf.fullerton.edu*.... page, I can click the extension icon (maybe it pops up), and then on that page I can edit the DOM. I would like it to be contained to 1 page. On my phone or I'd be coding this all out, but that would mean I can just use send msg (not executescript) and it should work as a content script and be able to access the dom, not as just a background.js script (no dom access) like it was?